# Upgrading from postgres-9.3 to postgres-9.5

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, ubuntu-16.04, postgresql-9.5

I need to use the new `jsonb` field in postgres so I decided to upgrade to 9.5 in my ununtu 16.04 LTS. I followed this [tutorial](https://blog.chaps.io/2016/02/08/upgrading-postgresql-from-9-4-to-9-5-on-ubuntu-15-10.html) , but when it gets to the command `pg_upgradecluster 9.3 main`, I get the error that `cluster configuration already exists`. I checked other tutorials and found that I could get the list of clusters with `pg_lsclusters`. But the command always shows only the 9.3 cluster. Any attempt to create the 9.5 cluster always results to `cluster configuration already exists`. I purged the 9.5 and installed again multiple times but the same result. At last I decided to purge all the postgres installations I have after backing up my 9.3 cluster with `pg_dumpall`.
Now I have decided to install the 9.5 freshly but I still get the same thing. When I install `pg_lsclusters` shows nothing and after starting postgres `psql` always returns `psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

Right now I'm so tired and frustrated. Please if anyone has any possible solution or suggestion, help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be from the version 9.5 in the postgres repositories. I installed 9.6 and everything worked like magic. Had I known there was a stable 9.6 earlier, I wouldn't have wasted 6 hours of my life in something I could have done for 10 minutes. Anyway, I'm happy I have have a working postgres with jsonb field